# Why does my lawn grass have woody stems?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

Location: Cambridgeshire, UK.

My new-build lawn grass has patches with really woody stems that make the lawn look patchy and unattractive. Is it a weed or something that happened to the regular grass? My plant identification app failed.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That grass looks really dry.  Did it go to seed in a dry spell?

Comment: Is this the first time you've cut it? Any idea when it was last cut previously?  Before you mowed, did you notice any dense clumps of grass that were a bit taller than the rest of the lawn, or does the whole lawn have these woody stems since cutting?

Comment: Last cut was before the winter. It was the first time I cut it this year - unfortunately I can’t really recall any clumps and didn’t take any photos. The woody stems aren’t found over the whole lawn.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities as follows - 1. these hard stalks have formed because the grass hasn't been cut for so long or 2. you have some meadow grass mixed in with your lawn. Meadow type grasses form clumps, grow faster and are often tough at the base. Since we can't see what the grass was like before it was cut, I suggest you mow it again when it needs it in the next couple of weeks and watch how it develops over time - the tough stems may disappear, but if not, leaving it to grow for a bit later in the season should allow any meadow grasses present to be more obvious. If there is meadow grass, these will need to be dug out, roots and all, the holes filled in with garden soil and then seeded on top - there is no weedkiller that selects for specific types of grass.