Thick/dead stalk issue in lawn
Bit of a newbie but been trying to get my lawn looking better this year.
I over seeded and fertilised in late April. Grass is growing fine and the actual grass is looking ok, however, I have lots of stalky type stems scattered throughout the lawn which appear to be dead as they are brown/yellow. They are very tough and roots seem very strong and deep if you try to pull them out.
Just looking for advice on what they are and how to get rid of them?

Before concluding a decision  I want to ask if have you overfertilized the lawn if not are scattered stems different from the actual grass? If so, then you might be dealing with a weed problem

Hi, I don’t think I over fertilised. I followed the dose instructions of 35g/sqm… the stems are certainly different to the grass. Any idea what weed it could be and how would I get rid of it?

Which continent/region? What type of lawns did you have before overseeding? (Some some overseeding seeds contains herbicides, to kill weeds).

I’m in the UK. The lawn has never been great so suspect it will be a weed issue. It was there prior to overseeding but has gotten worse (maybe due to the fertiliser?)

You should share separate images of the weed and the original grass for better identification.

This answer https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/64546/why-does-my-lawn-grass-have-woody-stems to a question should be helpful to you
